# SVG: Inline or Link

Tags: css, svg

I'm creating a navigation menu and would like to use SVG images. My question is simple, but I've searched everywhere and cannot find a great answer.

Which is better to use (user experience, loading speed of web page) an embedded SVG in an 'a' tag? Or link the SVG in the 'a' tag?

I want to be able to edit the SVG's color, and use a hover effect.

Comment: "***The problem with both <img> and background-image...** Is that you don't get to control the innards of the SVG with CSS like you can with the following two ways*." and "***inline svg** can be nice because the image comes over right in the document and doesn't need to make an additional HTTP request. In other words, it has the same advantages as using a Data URI. It has the same disadvantages too. A potentially "bloated" document, a big chunk of crap right in the document you're trying to author, and inability to cache*" [css-tricks: using svg](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style the SVG with CSS, then you need to inline the SVG.  An external SVG file cannot be styled - unless you add the CSS into the SVG file itself.